# Code within try block still panics when calling unwrap on a None value

Tags: rust

```
#![feature(try_blocks)]
pub fn is_valid(code: &str) -> bool {
    let result: Result<bool, ()> = try {
        code.chars()
            .filter(|x| !x.is_whitespace())
            .map(|x| x.to_digit(10).unwrap())
            .rev()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(i, num)| match i % 2 != 0 {
                true => {
                    let doubled = 2 * num;
                    match doubled > 9 {
                        true => doubled - 9,
                        false => doubled,
                    }
                }
                false => num,
            })
            .sum::<u32>()
            % 10
            == 0
    };
    match result {
        Ok(value) => value,
        Err(_) => false,
    }
}
```

On some inputs, this programme panics, and I don't understand why. The `to_digit` returns an `Option`, but it is unwrapped, and the `None` case should be caught by the `try` block. My understanding is that if the `.unwrap` is called on a `None` value, the try block will return a `Result::Error`, which the final `match` will convert into `false`.

I am new to Rust!

I did try `x.to_digit(10).ok_or("Error").unwrap()` to turn it into a `Result` rather than an `Option`, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Apparently it's a new unstable syntax, separate from the old `try!` macro: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html

Comment: If you're new to Rust I don't recommend experimenting with poorly documented nightly unstable features. If you [read the docs on `try_blocks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html) it says nothing about catching panics, so I don't know where you got the idea that it would do that in the first place, other than it being a preconceived idea you got from your experience of using `try` blocks in other languages. Anyway, if you're just learning Rust please consider sticking to stable Rust, that'll offer a much easier and simpler learning experience.

Comment: @pretzelhammer That's exactly how I ended up with the assumption that it would catch panics...  The advice on sticking to stable Rust seems reasonable, thank you!

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I'll close the question, since it's based on faulty assumptions!

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that if the .unwrap is called on a None value, the try block will return a Result::Err

Actually no: from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

> Panics if the self value equals None.

A 'Panic' is very different from returning a `Result::Err`. Panics are intended to be used for unrecoverable errors, while returning a `Result::Err` is used for everyday potentially recoverable errors. See the [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) chapter in the rust book for more discussion on the differences.

As you had hinted, instead of `unwrap` you can use [`ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) to transform the `Option` into a `Result`:

```rust
x.to_digit(10).ok_or("Error")?
```

Note that I put a '?' on the end, instead of the `unwrap` you tried. The effect of the `?` is:

- If the value is a `Result::Err` then it is returned from the enclosing function or try block
- If the value is a `Result::Ok` then it is unwrapped.

It desugars something like this:

```rust
match x.to_digit(10).ok_or("Error") {
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
    Ok(v) => v
}
```

As mentioned by some in the comments, you may be better off keeping away from unstable features if you are new to rust, although I don't think that is the cause of this issue.